# Java desktop apps

Tags: java, desktop-application

Are there any professional Java desktop applications in use? I'm asking this because I started to study Java and would like to know it's possibilities and/or domains in which java is used.

Comment: Google reveals this: http://community.java.net/java-desktop.  Why didn't you read that first and ask specific questions?  Also a SO search reveals questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168676/recommended-books-on-desktop-application-development-using-mvc and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720/packaging-java-apps-for-the-windows-linux-desktop.  With all that information, why ask such a vague question?

Comment: @Lott Firstly I didn't want to read the contents of the web proposed by you mainly for the reason that I needed simple and quick answer which would basicaly list some of pro apps written in java instead of searching God knows how long to achive the same effect. Secondly what's vague about my question. All I'm asking for is to list professional apps written in java in order to be able to download them and check how they look like and behave. What's vague about it?

Comment: Seems we only get developer tools so far. A little surprising to me.

Comment: So basically one can say (based on answers below) that professional Java desktop apps virtually do not exists? Is that fair conclusion? So for what purpose is java used then?

Comment: me knowing you: Vague as in "professional" is an undefined term.  Do you mean "apps for which you pay"?  If so, please update the question to define what you mean by "professional".  The "possibilities" makes no sense -- Java has infinite possibilities.  The "domains" makes no sense -- Java can be applied to any domain.  What are you trying to find?

Comment: It seems most Java desktop apps are for developers. Android apps are written on Java, but it seems that nowadays (2019) there are few Java desktop (PC) apps targeted at end users. Related reading: https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/3tozqi/why_is_java_desktop_considered_to_be_dead/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the largest existing ones are from the software development space (thats also the primary domain for desktop applications) like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) or [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [Rational Software architect](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/swarchitect/websphere/).

Another big one is the [IBM DB2 Tools](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/) (not the database itself). (But if you want to see something as a reference better not take these because they are slow as hell).

Answer (score 2):

http://netbeans.org/

http://argouml.tigris.org/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.magicdraw.com

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea

Answer (score 1):

check out this SO question..its answers contain a list of desktop applications running on java.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521110/examples-of-good-java-desktop-applications)

Answer (score 0):

DumpHD is a well-written application in Java; it works perfectly in Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that both Eclipse and Netbeans also offer a platform for developing applications on and not just an IDE.
Here is a sample of applications written using the Netbeans Platform

http://platform.netbeans.org/screenshots.html