# Developing Desktop Application using Java

Tags: java, netbeans, desktop-application

I was figuring out on the net, how to create a desktop application with Java. I found I can do it through NetBeans IDE. Is there a better IDE?

Can you suggest me a suitable eBook for learning Java NetBeans?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/168890/388053

Answer (score 1):

There are three major IDEs for Java:

NetBeans - https://netbeans.org/

Eclipse - http://www.eclipse.org/

IntelliJ - http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/ (This one is a commercial product.)

Pick your religion.

Comment: And two major GUI toolkits - Swing and SWT.

Comment: Any of these IDEs can do Swing GUI development. (I do like MyEclipse version of Eclipse for Swing screen design. It, too, is commercial. But it's cheap.) I wouldn't suggest doing SWT outside Eclipse.

Comment: Agreed on SWT. The standard distribution of Eclipse also well supports Swing design with the formerly commercial product WindowBuilder, now free after Google's acquisition of Instantiations.

Comment: Sometimes its better to not even use a Swing GUI Designer and organize the code yourself. But, if you are new, you will get better looking results faster. The designer will constrain what you can do with the user interface. All of these are probably good enough. (We didn't mention that IBMs version of Eclipse has a Swing GUI tool but I don't think they give it away.

Comment: Sometimes. But frequently it's useful to use -- and avoid code that breaks -- the WYSIWIG designer, for faster development *and maintenance*, regardless of the skill level of the original developer. We don't tend to write documents directly in PostScript, and the majority of forms don't require visual design directly in Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can create desktop application with `Java Swing GUI Toolkit`, which is a part of the `Java JDK`, regardless of the IDE. @Lee Meador gives you some to choose from.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/netbeans.html) is a tutorial on making a simple desktop application with NetBeans.

There are also tons of YouTube tutorials for beginners. Search for "Java tutorials" and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 0):

IDE preferences are fairly subjective.  Netbeans is not bad.  Eclipse is also a good IDE.  My favorite one, though, is IntelliJ IDEA.  They have a free Community Edition which lets you do a lot of things, but I paid for it to get full functionality.

As far as eBooks for learning about the IDEs, I would suggest just looking on the website of whatever IDE you end up choosing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I see things when it comes to IDE's:

NetBeans is fantastic for beginners, but the code it generates for the Swing WYSIWYG editor looks like absolute garbage. If you're okay with keeping the code in NetBeans and not worrying about how the code for you GUI looks, it's an excellent way to go if you don't feel like hard-coding Swing.

Eclipse is a very professional and powerful tool, but it's a bit daunting at times as well, and it's not quite as quick and easy to get things up and running. It has no built-in drag and drop Swing editor (although Google provides an excellent one called the Google Plugin for Eclipse) but it's got far and away the most powerful debugger I've ever used.

I don't know a lot about IntelliJ other than that it's also a good choice for beginners and professionals alike, but I haven't seen as much community support for it. That may just be because I've been an Eclipse die-hard for ages, but that's just how I see it.

What's more important than your IDE choice is that you figure out early on how to use it to its full potential. All three are excellent pieces of software, and all three will help you do whatever it is you want to build. But they can only help you if you learn to use their organizational tools, their editor/template options, their respective debuggers, etc. Honestly, I would say if you have any friends that are Java developers, choose whatever they're using at least for now so you have someone to go to when you don't understand how to use a particular option.